# products csv import categories not updated in magento2

Tags: magento2, import, products, category-id

I'm importing product sku and category ids using product import in magento2.
but not working please anyone help me.

```
eg: sku,category_ids
test_123,2,5,12
```

thanks

Comment: have you reindexed the data after upload? Was the upload successful?

Comment: Yes I did the reindex but products are not assign to categories.

Answer (score 0):

You've to quote the fields!

eg: sku,category_ids
test_123,"2,5,12"

otherwise for the importer only the "2" value is considered.